# How can I compensate illumination changes in iris images other than using Retinex theory?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, image-enhancement

I want to make an effective illumination compensation on iris images and I want this compensation to be based on color i.e. illumination compensation using color rather than texture. I corrected my images for various mechanical errors but I want a simple algorithm to compensate the illumination based on color. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question, but somewhat off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Try subtracting a low-pass copy of the same image?

Answer (score 1):

What you are interested in is white balancing (i.e. achieving color constancy). One of the simplest algorithms is the Gray-World algorithm and I would try that one first because it's very easy to implement (even though it's not very precise).

You also might want to try some Retinex based algorithms. If so, visit this site: http://www.fer.unizg.hr/ipg/resources/color_constancy/

It contains C++ implementations of several Retinex-based color constancy algorithms.